# Perl regex captures non-capturing groups

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I am using perl to parse CSV file. I use regex to parse it instead of any library. I know, there is CSV parser library available, and not only one, but I just decided I want to use REGEX.

I created I think a quite nice and working regular expression for this. I originally created other applications, which take a regular expression only to parse files. And I wanted to reuse it for this case.

I want to use the beauty of perl put it in one line:

```
my $text = '"",hi there,"","2018-04-23,\" 13:14:53",,hostname,mac,"ipaddress",199';

my @data = $text =~ m/(?:^|,)(?:"(|.*?[^\\])"|([^,]*))(?:|$)/g;
```

However, when I do that in one-liner perl regex captures even non-capturing groups.

Here is a testing code:

```
my $text = '"",hi there,"","2018-04-23,\" 13:14:53",,hostname,mac,"ipaddress",199';

my @data = $text =~ m/(?:^|,)(?:"(|.*?[^\\])"|([^,]*))(?:|$)/g;
foreach (@data) { print "a --${_}--\n"; }

while ($text =~ m/(?:^|,)(?:"(|.*?[^\\])"|([^,]*))(?:|$)/cg) {
    print "b --${1}${2}--\n";
}
```

Results for "a" dump are:

```
a ----
a ----
a ----
a --hi there--
a ----
a ----
a --2018-04-23,\" 13:14:53--
a ----
a ----
a ----
a ----
a --hostname--
a ----
a --mac--
a --ipaddress--
a ----
a ----
a --199--
```

You can see there extra empty lines as opposed to the correct results from "b" dump:

```
b ----
b --hi there--
b ----
b --2018-04-23,\" 13:14:53--
b ----
b --hostname--
b --mac--
b --ipaddress--
b --199--
```

Has any body met with this issue?
Thank you for your answers / ideas / bug findings.

Comment: Seriously - regex is the wrong tool for this job. I know you say "you want to use it". but ... CSV is contextual - it  can contain nested quotes, linefeeds etc. `regex` is not contextual, so it will never work exhaustively. `Text::CSV` is good at what it does.

Comment: *"I want to use the beauty of perl put it in one line"* The "beauty of Perl" is not in writing incomprehensible code that replicates the function of a tried and tested module.

Comment: Your string `"",hi there,"","2018-04-23,\" 13:14:53",,hostname,mac,"ipaddress",199` is not valid CSV data.

Comment: There is no point at all in `(?:|$)`: it will always match.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as I posted my question I realised that issue are not the non-capturing groups, but actually capturing groups, which only one of them has a value and the other is empty at the time.

The culprit is this section of the regex:

```
(?:"(|.*?[^\\])"|([^,]*))
```

Everything went all right after replacing non-capturing group with [branch-reset](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) feature:

```
(?|"(|.*?[^\\])"|([^,]*))
```

So final working correct one-liner is:

```
my @data = $text =~ m/(?:^|,)(?|"(|.*?[^\\])"|([^,]*))(?:|$)/g;
```

Hopefully someone will find this information useful.

Comment: TBH your issue is that you're using `regex` instead of `Text::CSV`. I know you "decided that you just want to use regex" but ... that's using a hammer to put screws in. Sure, it can be made to work, but it'll never be anything other than ugly.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see this one-liner ugly. It's a perl syntax. 

And as I also mentioned, I created the regex before for other tools, software, where I can not modify a code. That software takes regex only and output format, where I used   "$1$2", so I didn't notice the issue.

Just to add, I posted this question more as curiosity. I was wondering if anybody else came across the same. I couldn't believe it would be a bug in perl and that's why I asked here.
I was already heading to use `Text::CSV`.

Comment: @petom: I'm surprised at the upvotes your comment has received when you're basically defending a fairly impregnable regex pattern that still has bugs. I also suspect that it will be slower that `Text::CSV::XS`. I wonder if the people who agree with you would like to comment?

Comment: @Borodin I didn't post it for the purpose of CSV parsing. CSV was just a use case. Main purpose of this post is "special" or "magic of" regular expressions. I believe people came across similar issue too, when they had multiple subgroups where one excludes the other, and they wanted to have results in $1 every time. I needed this in multiple projects before, but usually "$1$2" workaround was good enough. I used the similar regex (approach, not necessarily CSV parsing) in python and other scripting languages. This case made me finally to do some search through regex docs.

Comment: @petom: The `(?|...)` construct is hardly a special one. `$1$2` will result in an *uninitialized* warning because one or other of the captures must be `undef`. If your post is just about celebrating the loveliness of Perl then it is off topic, and the question itself doesn't make that at all clear.